# Why am I getting error in tsconfig when I install React TS from Vite?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, tsconfig

I have installed React TS in Vite, but it is showing me an error in `tsconfig.json`. I can't figure out why because I haven't even tried to change the installed code yet. What is the reason?

```
[tsconfig.json ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obFT4.png)

> 1. error: Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier.
>
> See more: [https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution)
>
> vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-sandbox/workbench/workbench.html
>
> Option '--resolveJsonModule' cannot be specified without 'node' module resolution strategy.
>
> 2. error: Allow imports to include TypeScript file extensions. Requires '--moduleResolution bundler' and either '--noEmit' or '--emitDeclarationOnly' to be set.
>
> 3. error: Enable importing .json files
```

Answer (score 38):

Try changing the typescript version in your vs code to "Use workspace version"
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpDob.png)

Comment: But I don't have the "workspace version"

Comment: Run "npm install" before that

Comment: You are correct, this fix it for me

Comment: How will I get this option

Comment: to get this option, click on the curly braces near `Typescript React` on the bottom panel of VSCode, click `Select Version` and the option to use the workspace version will pop up on the top of your screen

Answer (score 1):

Adding the settings.json fix, which is in effect the same as the the top fix

This can be resolved by adding the following to your settings.json inside of your .vscode folder

```
{
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```